# Calculate Num_Index_Pages for sizing design

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index

I don't understand [Step2 #8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms178085) Calculate the number of number of non-leaf pages in the index.  I am not sure I understand the "Level".

I have `Num_Leaf_Pages=508` & `Index_Rows_Per_Page=476`

I don't understand how they arrived at
 
`Num_Index_Pages = 1000/(253)+ 1000/(252) + 1000/(251) = 1 + 2 + 40 = 43`
"which is the number of pages described in the example."

1000/253 does not give 1, and 1000/252 does not give 2...What am I missing with regard to the "level" and how can I plug my values of 508 and 476 in and be confident with the result.

Comment: You are not the only one - It's the bit about "round each summand up to the next whole number". Here is a blog post with information on how to create a spreadsheet http://www.sqlmunkee.com/2010/12/estimating-size-of-clustered-index.html and here are some scripts to calculate this on your database

Comment: @Spörri I'm surprised I didn't come across this blog post!  Very Helpful!  first time doing this :P

Comment: enjoy, I forgot to paste the other link: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/indexsize/

Comment: The index levels usually take up a tiny fraction of the table size. You can just leave them out or add 1% or so.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to implement the same, I ended up using this to approximate at a decent level of accuracy:

```sql
WHILE (@NonLeafLevels > 1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempIndexPages FLOAT;

    -- TempIndexPages may be exceedingly small, so catch any arith overflows and call it 0
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @TempIndexPages = @NumLeafPages / POWER(@IndexRowsPerPage, @NonLeafLevels);
        SET @NumIndexPages = @NumIndexPages + @TempIndexPages;
        SET @NonLeafLevels = @NonLeafLevels - 1;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @NonLeafLevels = @NonLeafLevels - 1;
    END CATCH
END;
```